# 403 - Forbidden with Apache and Django on Windows with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, windows, apache

I have looked through numerous tutorials and posts related to Apache and Django on Windows to try to solve my issue. I can run the Django project via the development server and know that my Apache install is working. I know that my issue resides in the configuration of Apache to get it to work with Django. My configuration is shown below. I have made sure that the server project folder is accessible to Everyone with read and execute permissions. I have tried setting the paths with the "C:" and without. Setting the server's filesystem directory access to "Require all granted" (not recommended) does not help. What am I missing?

Django settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'INDmain.wsgi.application'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

httdp.conf

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf # "#" is removed from start of line.
LoadFile "c:/users/user/appdata/local/programs/python/python36/python36.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/user/appdata/local/programs/python/python36/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/user/appdata/local/programs/python/python36"

WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/INDmain/main/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath "C:/INDmain"
<Directory "C:/INDmain/main">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost

    Alias "/" "C:/INDmain/main"
    <Directory "C:/INDmain/main">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias "/static" "C:/INDmain/static"
    <Directory "C:/INDmain/static">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Granted I only implement on Linux, so the following may not be helpful, but my standard approach would be to create a `sitename_co_uk.conf` file within `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

The following would be the content of the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@sitename.co.uk
    ServerName sitename.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.sitename.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sitename
    WSGIDaemonProcess sitename python-path=/var/www/sitename python-home=/var/www/sitename/env
    WSGIProcessGroup sitename
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/sitename/core/wsgi.py

    Alias /robots.txt /var/www/sitename/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/sitename/static/favicon.ico

    Alias /media/ /var/www/sitename/media/
    Alias /static/ /var/www/sitename/static/

    <Directory /var/www/sitename/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/sitename/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/sitename/core/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/sitename/core>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This means I have my site actually in the directory `/var/www/sitename'.  This directory will contain a virtual environment in`env`and the`manage.py`file.  My`settings.py`,`wsgi.py`etc are within the sub-directory`core`.

This is enabled using `a2ensite sitename_co_uk.conf`.

It should work in a similar fashion on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

After getting this up and running in a Docker container running Ubuntu, I was able to get my Windows version to work after copying the project into a directory under the Apache directory and making some configuration changes for the new location. Final configuration files are below.

Web site/project layout

```
\Apache24
--> www
    --> INDapp
        --> INDmain
            --> INDmain
            --> main
            db.sqlite3
            manage.py
```

Django settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['<ip_address>']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'main.apps.MainConfig',

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'INDmain.wsgi.application'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

httdp.conf

```
LoadFile "c:/users/rsloma/appdata/local/programs/python/python36/python36.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/rsloma/appdata/local/programs/python/python36/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/rsloma/appdata/local/programs/python/python36"

WSGIPythonPath C:/Apache24/www/INDapp/INDmain
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ServerAlias <ip_address>

    DocumentRoot C:/Apache24/www/INDapp

    Alias /static "C:/Apache24/www/INDapp/INDmain/main/static"  
    <Directory "C:/Apache24/www/INDapp/INDmain/main/static">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory "C:/Apache24/www/INDapp/INDmain/INDmain">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / C:/Apache24/www/INDapp/INDmain/INDmain/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```